# d3's .call() passes incorrect selection when the current selection is div

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

http://jsfiddle.net/kWhF7/6/

The beginning selection is the div container element.

```
function chart(selection)
{
    createSVGCanvas(selection)// <----  Works
    //selection.call(createSVGCanvas) // <----  Doesn't Work
    .call(calculateScales) 
    .call(dataLayer)

    return this;
}

function createSVGCanvas(selection)
{
    //This properly returns an svg element, but in the broken version
    // the NEXT .call'd function (calculateScales), has a selection of the
    // div#svg_canvas, NOT the svg.

    return selection.append("svg")
      .attr("width", config.width)
      .attr("height", config.height);
}
```

It seems to me that when the current selection is a div (or NOT an svg element), the d3's .call function seems to pass the wrong element to the next .call function.

I can definitely use the working version, but the broken version looks more of a d3 coding style.

Any explanation as to why the next .Call function is receiving the div rather than the svg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#call):

> The call operator always returns the current selection, regardless of the return value of the specified function.

That is, your intended use explicitly won't work. The uncommented code in your jsfiddle is the correct way to do it.

Comment: We want to return the changed selection because the following .call()'s are expecting the selection to be the svg not the div.If we do what you stated above, then we'll have to reconfigure all of the other .call() functions to first filter there selection.

Comment: but on a different note, why would selection.call(createSVGCanvas) fail and createSVGCanvas(selection) work?